# Time warping analysis from HMD's Data-Log

Tags: python, r, time, virtual-reality, datasheet

I have a very little knowledge about time warping. I retrieved the position of the player inside a VE every 0.05 seconds. I have done this for 40 player that interacted with a device, and 40 player that interacted with ANOTHER device. I need to compare overall position of the players in the VE with one device comparing it to the other. By saying that I mean that I need to reconstruct in time the position of my players into the VE and see if it changes between the two devices used. Some people suggested me to approach to Time Warping analyses in order to achieve this aim.
Could someone help me out by providing me a script for Rstudio (that includes also graphic visualization) and moreover explain to me how is the logic behind time warping analyses?

Thank you in advance if you would like to help me! I will be very grateful

So far I didn't try much not knowing the concept and the anlyses a part trying to look at some clustering video that didn't really helped me. I'm a bit lost on the topic and I would like a way to start approaching it with some documentation regarding the topic.